# I am an American with a US passport.I have a 15 hour layover in Paris.

Tags: visas, france, layovers, us-citizens

I am an American with a US passport.I have a 15 hour layover in Paris. Can I leave the aiport to tour the city? Do I need a visa?

Comment: As long as you haven't visited in the previous 180 days, then YES you can leave the airport, and NO you do not need a visa.  Frankfurt is the same as Paris where visa rules are concerned.